# What does a relationship owner mean in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

```
@Entity
public class Troop {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="troop")
    public Set<Soldier> getSoldiers() {
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Soldier {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="troop_fk")
    public Troop getTroop() {
    ...
}
```

I am struggling with documentation on this:

```
Troop has a bidirectional one to many relationship with Soldier through the troop property. You don't have to (must not) define any physical mapping in the mappedBy side.
```

So for example the following code:

```
Troup t = new Troup();
t.getSoldiers().add(soldier);
```

What would the difference be if I just called `session.saveOrUpdate(t)`, and if I just called
`session.saveOrUpdate(s)`?  MappedBy defines troup as the owner, but what specifically does this mean?  Because I would expect that if I save the soldier object, surely the troop_fk column will be saved correctly?  And if I just save the troup object, surely the the soldier foreign key will still be update correctly when cascading?  I really can't see the difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the owner is the entity which sets the foreign key in the database on flushing.

the code:

```
Troup t = new Troup();
t.getSoldiers().add(soldier);
session.SaveOrUpdate(t);
session.Flush();
```

without cascading:

```
throws references transient instances
```

with cascading and owner = troop

```
INSERT INTO troops (id, ...) VALUES (1, ...)
INSERT INTO soldiers (..., troop_fk) VALUES (..., NULL)
UPDATE soldiers SET troop_fk=1    <- troop sets its key
```

with cascading and owner = soldier

```
INSERT INTO troops (id, ...) VALUES (1, ...)
INSERT INTO soldiers (..., troop_fk) VALUES (..., 1) <- soldier saves the reference
```

Comment: For more information check section 2.2.5.3.1.1. at http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-association. With info on how to toggle the ownership from one entity to another for the above example.

Comment: with cascading and owner = troop, INSERT INTO soldiers (..., troop_fk) VALUES (..., NULL). If in soldiers table toop_fk is not nullable then while executing the query will hibernate thows error. Is it developer has to take care of that?

Comment: if the column is not nullable you simply can't use "cascading and owner = troop"